# VSCode Extension Authoring - Storage for app secrets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension that needs to authenticate using OAuth. 
Is there a storage space in vscode namespace where app secret and access tokens can be stored securely? If not, any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the SecretStorage utility is provided for that.
Secrets are persisted across reloads and are independent of the current opened workspace.

[API documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SecretStorage)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR. No, as of November 2017.

There are some discussions on the credential API for Visual Studio Code extensions([#15414](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15414), [#31131](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31131)), but as of November 2017, this feature is stalled and not planned in the near future.

As a workround, you can check `globalState` and `workspaceState` in [`vscode.ExtensionContext`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nameextensioncontextaspan-classcodeitem-id1139extensioncontextspan) as the solution to store data, but you might need to handle encryption/decryption yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to *see* this string after you store (like in `User Settings`, you should use `context.globalState`.

Example Extension [Tagged Comment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.tagged-comment).

This is how it stores the value:

```
context.globalState.update('lastTagged', str);
```

This is how it loads the value:

```
let lastTagged = context.globalState.get('lastTagged', '');
```